# Using Google Drive API with Javascript prototypes

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

So instead of doing the standard copy & paste from the examples in Google's docs of Javascript with global variables, I want to encapsulate everything using prototypes.

My function starts with this:

```
define(function (require){
    'use strict';
    ...
```

but the interesting point at which I am blocked now is:

```
GoogleDrive.prototype.loadAPI = function() {
    window.gapi.load('picker', {'callback': this.onPickerApiLoad});
};

GoogleDrive.prototype.onPickerApiLoad = function() {
    this.pickerApiLoaded = true;
    this.createPicker();
};
```

That doesn't work because `this` inside the callback is not my `GoogleDrive` function any more, so I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pickerApiLoaded' of undefined
```

How would I connect that `.onPickerApiLoad` to the right scope?

**UPDATE:**

Prompted by @Jon's answer, I looked into Underscore's `bind` method source code and it uses `call`, so I tried to do the same, with a function that returns a version of my prototype function bound to the context I want:

```
GoogleDrive.prototype.loadAPI = function() {
        var that = this;
        googleAPI.load('picker', {'callback': function() { return that.onPickerApiLoad.call(that) }});
    };
```

This seems to work (have to confirm), but not that elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resorted to `call` and an anonymous function, using which I can pass my own context:

```
var that = this;
googleAPI.load('picker', { 'callback': function() {
    return that.onPickerApiLoad.call(that)
} } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could get this to work using the [bind](https://lodash.com/docs#bind) function of Underscore or Lo-Dash (a drop-in Underscore replacement):

```
GoogleDrive.prototype.loadAPI = function() {
    window.gapi.load('picker', {'callback': _.bind(this.onPickerApiLoad, this)});
};
```

Comment: I noticed Google returns a promise if you don't pass the callback in, is it possible to use that instead of another library?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, only `gapi.client.load` returns a promise, and that API is (confusingly) completely separate.